# Newbie, Unable to install scanner Software for Brother MFC L8850CDW?

Tags: scanner

Newbie, Unable to install scanner Software(S/W)  for Brother MFC L8850CDW?

Hi, I've tried to [install the Brother scanner S/W](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl8850cdw_us_eu_as&os=128)  onto my pc. I tried both the Scanner & the Printer downloads but unsuccessfull?  I'm not very familar with command line verbage & may be my problem. (Ubuntu 14.04).

I paid a Linux Pro to install drivers to Print & Scan with my new MFC ~18 months ago but when we moved from Phx,AZ to Redlands,CA the scanner would not work??  Regreatably,No Meetup Or Install Fest here in Redlands,CA.

Thank you in advance, Mitch Stanley

Comment: Forgot to add- it's on a network & not USB connection.

Comment: Welcome at AskUbuntu. To help us help you, you need to provide as much (relevant) detail as possible; How did you try to install, it was unsuccessful but how did you notice, what were the error messages? Have you tried other solutions to solve this problem?
See also [about] and [ask]

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience, it's better to link the device to pc with an usb cable, at least the first time you install it.

I think that is enough to go here:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl8850cdw_us_eu_as

then select at STEP 1 "Linux", and then at STEP 2 "Linux (deb)". Click on "Search" and then download the driver, according to the version of your operating system (32bit or 64bit).

To check the version of your operating system, open the terminal, and write:

```
uname –m
```

If the answer is:

```
x86_64
```

then your system is a 64 bit system;
otherwise, if the answer is

```
i686
```

or

```
i386
```

your system is a 32 bit system.

Once you have downloaded the .deb file, just double-click on it and then install it.

Hope this helps.